# Onion Omega2+ npm install fail chown

Tags: node.js, npm-install

i have a Onion Omega2+ with 2go microSD card ...

i make a .npmrc file because module don't enought space

```
prefix="/tmp/mounts/SD-P1/.npm-global"
cache="/tmp/mounts/SD-P1/.npm-cache"
```

But all time a try a npm install, i got error like :

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.46
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "jethro"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! path /tmp/mounts/SD-P1/.npm-
cache/jethro/4.4.0/package/package.json.09e2fd52e455f922d8d1f89baf5f60f4
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall chown
```

Comment: Permissions problem? Try `chown -R ``whoami`` /tmp/mounts/SD-P1`

Comment: root@Omega-B321:/tmp/mounts# ll
    drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            60 Jan  3 21:13 .
    drwxrwxrwt   28 root     root           700 Jan  3 22:05 ..
    lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            25 Jan  3 19:11 SD-P1 -> /tmp/run/mountd/mmcblk0p1
root@Omega-B321:/tmp/mounts# chown -R root /tmp/mounts/SD-P1
    chown: /tmp/mounts/SD-P1: Operation not permitted

Comment: root@Omega-B321:/tmp/run/mountd# ll
drwxr-xr-x    7 1000     1000         16384 Jan  1  1970 mmcblk0p1

Comment: Well, that operation not permitted again. Means either you do not own the device or the device is not writable.

Comment: @Zlatko i have read linux use user 1000 for automount micro sd and usb ...
i can't change user of sd-card ... npm can't change right and fail :/

Comment: Yes, this is not a node/npm question. It's about the system on your omega. Try posting a question about hhow to make microSD card writable, if it is not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my microSD as FAT partition ... when linux mount the partition automatic set user as 1000 ...

format sd card in EXT2 and it work ;)